# Overriding operators/begin/end of a custom Array class

Tags: c++

For an exercise we have to implement an array with custom bounds in various different languages, and one of them happens to be c++. Unfortunately i have never had to deal with c++ and am now struggling to get it done. I believe i have the right "core" of the header finished. The idea is that the user specifies bounds in a template and the class fakes this with help of an inner array. We were specifically told to overwrite the [] operator and implement begin() and end() functions. I am currently stuck at the visual studio debugger saying the following:

```
Error   C2228   left of '.end' must have class/struct/union
```

The gcc compiler is saying:

```
In file included from Aufgabe1.test.cpp:2:
array.h: In instantiation of 'typename std::__cxx11::list<T>::iterator Array<T, L, H>::begin() [with T = int; int L = -2; int H = 1; typename std::__cxx11::list<T>::iterator = std::_List_iterator<int>]':
Aufgabe1.test.cpp:16:15:   required from here
array.h:29:25: error: request for member 'begin' in '((Array<int, -2, 1>*)this)->Array<int, -2, 1>::innerArray', which is of non-class type 'int [4]'
       return innerArray.begin;
              ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
array.h: In instantiation of 'typename std::__cxx11::list<T>::iterator Array<T, L, H>::end() [with T = int; int L = -2; int H = 1; typename std::__cxx11::list<T>::iterator = std::_List_iterator<int>]':
Aufgabe1.test.cpp:16:15:   required from here
array.h:33:25: error: request for member 'end' in '((Array<int, -2, 1>*)this)->Array<int, -2, 1>::innerArray', which is of non-class type 'int [4]'
       return innerArray.end;
              ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
```

Simply put i have no way of continuing from here since searching for these errors bring no clarification for someone who worked primarily with java so far. How can i solve thse issues and is my implementation of this Array otherwise correct ?

EDIT:
Had to remove the code

Comment: My suggestion would be to learn some C++ before taking on such a task. Start with simpler programs, and build up complexity gradually.

Comment: As it is an exercise task i have no choice of what program to start with.

Comment: You could choose a better course or book.

Comment: Does the exercise task forbid you from learning the language by writing simpler programs and building up complexity gradually? That would seem like a strange requirement.

Comment: It actually implicitly does since we are supposed to deduce how to write code for various languages from programming paradigms.

Comment: @Soliture That's a terrible way to learn a programming language.  You miss out on relevant details like `static_assert` and `std::begin`.

Comment: Is learning stuff not a thing anymore?

Comment: @juanchopanza I'd love to learn more about c++, specifically why i get the errors above :)

Comment: In C++, plain arrays don't have a `.begin` or an `.end`.

Comment: Why are you trying to return `std::list<T>::iterator` when you do not actually have any `std::list<T>` objects

Comment: I looked up examples of implementations of custom begin() and end() functions, but I see the point. I should have used an std::array and return a std::array<...>::iterator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error message you mention explains the problem fairly well:

> Error   C2228   left of '.end' must have class/struct/union

The second group of messages tells you where this occurs, specifically when you try to use `innerArray.end`. The thing to the left of ".end" is `innerArray`, which is not declared as a `class`, `struct`, or `union`. (It's an array of `T`.)

So this comes down to the fact that (C-style) arrays do not have member functions. If you need an "end" function, maybe you should look into [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), which wraps C-style arrays in a `class`. (If the requirement is to *overwrite* certain functions instead of *implement* them, this is the "array" your instructor likely had in mind.)

Comment: You're right that C-style arrays do not have member functions; however they definitely do have ends.

Comment: I have corrected the question, I am indeed supposed to implement the end() and begin() functions, not override.

Comment: I'll correct my approach by wrapping my inner array using a std::array and using its functions to implement end() and  begin(). Thank you.

Comment: @M.M A C-style array most certainly does NOT have an `.end()`.

Comment: @JaMiT I mean "end" as in the English word "end". It does not have member functions

Comment: @M.M Given the ambiguity of English, I have inserted a '.' into my answer. However, I still do not feel that it is wrong to say a C-style array does not have an "end" on the basis that the language provides nothing to say where that end is. Hence the quotes around "end".

Comment: The language provides multiple ways to say where the end is. E.g. `std::end(innerArray)`, or `innerArray + length`

Comment: @M.M I do not consider `innerArray + length` as the language providing the end since the language is not the one providing `length`. I had overlooked `std::end` though.

Comment: @JaMiT You can compute `length` using `sizeof` , which is basically what `std::end` does for arrays